# SQL Server export table to .dat file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017-express

I'm using SQL Server 2017 Express, I have an `eventlog` table and i would like to export it to a .dat file, in order to reduce the size of my database. Is there any possible way to do this. Can anyone give me a hint about it if it's possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create another SQL Server? I am thinking a new SQL Server instance just for storing the old data and moving the data via a linked server+delete. The upside is you can still easily query it if need be. If you don't care about that, why back it up at all?

Comment: What do you mean `dat` file? That's not a specific format. Storing data into another file won't take *less* space either, unless you move it to another disk

Comment: The Export Data task in SSMS can export data to multiple targets, including flat files, Access, Excel, other databases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `bcp` out (export) your table as `.dat` file.
try the following:

**using Command prompt:**

```
bcp dbname.schemaname.eventlog out "path\eventlog.dat" -T -c'
```

or

**within SQL server:**

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "dbname.schemaname.eventlog" out "path\eventlog.dat" -T -c'
```

[**bcp Utility Details**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: There's no reason to use `master..xp_cmdshell`. Just open a command prompt